# ember-simple-auth cookieExpirationTime not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, devise, ember-simple-auth

I need to implement a "remember me" feature in my application. 
I am using the built-in devise authenticator and have the following as my Session Store:

```
// app/session-stores/application.js
import CookieStore from 'ember-simple-auth/session-stores/cookie';

export default CookieStore.extend({
  cookieName: 'myapp-session-cookie'
});
```

I have a `login-form` component with the following:

```
rememberMe: false,
setExpirationTime() {
  const expirationTime = this.get('rememberMe') ? (14 * 24 * 60 * 60) : null;
  this.set('session.store.cookieExpirationTime', expirationTime);    
},

actions: {
  authenticateWithDevise() {
    this.setExpirationTime();
    let { identification, password } = this.getProperties('identification', 'password');
    this.get('session').authenticate('authenticator:devise', identification, password).then(() => {
      this.sendAction('onLoggedIn');
    }).catch((reason) => {
      this.set('errorMessage', reason.errors[0]);
    });
  }
}
```

and of course in the corresponding template I have:

```
<form role="form" {{action "authenticateWithDevise" on="submit"}}>
  {{input type="email" value=identification placeholder="Email" class="icon-email"}}
  {{input type="password" value=password placeholder="Password" class="icon-lock"}}
  {{input id='remember_me' type='checkbox' checked=rememberMe}}
</form>
```

What happens is session is never remembered, no matter whether `cookieExpirationTime` was set or `null`.
My question is: should I also implement something else on the server side? I'm currently using devise's `rememberable`. Also, I've tried searching both here and on github but can only find conversations and code that seems obsolete, like this:

https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/pull/451

Can somebody please shed some light? Thanks!

Comment: I was thinking that the `authenticate` method in Ember Simple Auth's devise authenticator could accept a `rememberMe` param together with `identification` and `password` and send it to the server. In my Rails controller I would include the `Rememberable` module:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/rememberable.rb


and invoke its `remember_me` method if the `rememberMe` param is true. This would be a server-side alternative to `cookieExpirationTime` right?